# JS function is running twice

Tags: javascript, if-statement, iteration, custom-data-attribute

I have a js function that should change the value of a html data attribute value based on the current value. So in other words it should act like a toggle between 0 and 1 onclick. Anyways as per logging the current state I have noticed that the state is logged twice times per click. I want that after checking and changing the current value the function should end.

```js
const accordionTabs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper'));

accordionTabs.forEach(accordionTab => {
  accordionTab.addEventListener('click', function checkTabState() {
    let state = accordionTab.getAttribute('data-State');
    console.log(state);
    if ( state == "1" ) {
       accordionTab.setAttribute("data-State", "0");
    } else {
       accordionTab.setAttribute("data-State", "1");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#custom-faq-accordion {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FFF6E7;
  padding: 60px 0 230px;
  min-height: 75vh;
}
#custom-faq-accordion-wrapper {
  width: 1200px; 
}
#custom-faq-accordion-title {
  padding-bottom: 60px; 
}

.accordion input[name=panel] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.2em 1em 0.5em 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.14, 0.095, 0.87);
}
.accordion label::after {
  font-family:"obviously-wide";
  font-size: 39px;
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0.8em;
}
.accordion label:hover {
  color: black;
}
.accordion input:checked + label {
  color: black;
}
.accordion input:checked + label:after {
  font-family:"obviously-wide";
  font-size: 39px;
  content: "-";
  line-height: 0.8em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.accordion .accordion__content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2.5em 0 3em;
  color: black ;
  transition: height 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.865, 0.14, 0.095, 0.87);
}

.accordion .accordion__content .accordion__header {
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.accordion .accordion__content .accordion__body {
  font-size: 0.825em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

/* 
* Size Variations
*/
input[name=panel]:checked ~ .accordion__content.accordion__content--small {
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 7em;
  width: 95%;
}

input[name=panel]:checked ~ .accordion__content.accordion__content--med {
  height: auto;
}

input[name=panel]:checked ~ .accordion__content.accordion__content--large {
  height: auto;
}

.custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.border-black {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-radius: 59px;
  background-color: #fff6e7;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  will-change: transform;
}

.border-black:hover {
 animation: pressin 0.3s forwards;
}

.custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow.custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow.custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow  {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -6px;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 110px;
 background-color: #000;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;  
}

.border-black label {
  font-family: vulfSans_bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 43px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

@keyframes pressin {
  0%   {transform: translateY(0px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(6px);}
}
```

```html
<section id="custom-faq-accordion">
  <div id="custom-faq-accordion-wrapper">
    <h3 id="custom-faq-accordion-title" class="obviously-wide-black-90">FAQ</h3>
  <div class="accordion">
  <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper" data-State="0">
    <div class="border-black">
      <input type="checkbox" name="panel" id="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">
      <label for="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">Titel</label>
      <div class="accordion__content accordion__content--small">
        <div class="accordion__body obviously-regular-25">lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper" data-State="0">
    <div class="border-black">
      <input type="checkbox" name="panel" id="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">
      <label for="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">Titel</label>
      <div class="accordion__content accordion__content--small">
        <div class="accordion__body obviously-regular-25">lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper" data-State="0">
    <div class="border-black">
      <input type="checkbox" name="panel" id="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">
      <label for="panel-{{ block.settings.accordion_position }}">Titel</label>
      <div class="accordion__content accordion__content--small">
        <div class="accordion__body obviously-regular-25">lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add sample HTML to the snippet.

Comment: Perhaps you may have two elements with the same class name within each other, making the click register twice.

Comment: basically what I want at all is that while the accordion tab is checked / opened that the .custom-faq-accordion-button-shadow changes to display none. I struggeled what the best solution would be for this and came up with that js function plus adjusted css bassed on the data attribute

Comment: If you do some debugging to identify what is firing when, you'll note that the second of the three `accordionTabs` fires on every click no matter which one you actually click on. Which leads to the possibility of the central element overlapping both of it's siblings in some way. Your CSS is quite tangled, try stripping it back to it's basics.

Comment: Your `.accordion label` class is to blame for the double firing. Specifically `display:block` (though clicking any of them only toggles the first element in your snippet)

Comment: @pilchard thank you. Anyways I am struggeling to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine

Probably the problem is in another part of the code

```js
const accordionTabs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper'));

accordionTabs.forEach(accordionTab => {
  accordionTab.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const state = e.target.getAttribute('data-State');

    const nextState = (Number(state) + 1) % 2
    console.log({
      state,
      nextState
    })

    e.target.setAttribute("data-State", nextState);


  });
});
```

```css
.custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper" data-State="0">1</div>
<div class="custom-faq-accordion-button-wrapper" data-State="0">2</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my code snippet here with the associated html. Unfortunately in my project when I changed my js snippet with yours its still called twice times. Maybe that happened because of the input field? If so how can I solve that